# Specifying Associations in Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-datamapper

I want to specify following type of associations through FactoryGirl. I have three models A, B and C where model of C which is in DataMapper is as follows:

```
Class C do
   include DataMapper::Resource
   belongs_to :A, :key=>true
   belongs_to :B, :key=>true
end
```

I don't know how to specify this in FactoryGirl i.e. what I mean is I want to write like this:

```
factory :c do |c|
<To be Filled>
end
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about `DataMapper` (and how that fits in/if it's included in the factory definition) but for the associations, do this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :C do |c|
    ...
    c.association :a
    c.association :b
  end  

end
```

Answer (score 0):

License belongs to LicenseTemplate

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :license do
    start_date { Time.now}
    end_date   { Time.now + 30.days }

    factory :license_with_template do
      association :license_template, factory: :license_template
    end

    after(:build) do |doc|
      if doc.license_template
        doc.agents_count = doc.license_template.agents
        doc.requests = doc.license_template.requests
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the above code gives me two factories 'license' and 'license_with_template'. the after 'build' block initializes the values which need to be initialized before the object is saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :c do |f|
    f.a
    f.b
  end
end
```

if you create the factories for both `a` and `b` and you make sure that the names of the factories are the same as those of the model,that is all you need to specify the association. FactoryGirl will create both `a` and `b` every time you do: `FactoryGirl.create(:c)` . The association should be specified on one side only, preferably the belongs to side.